# Mount directories after taking input from 2 files

Tags: linux, scripting, mount

I would like to run a script which will take input from two files in order to mount multiple directories.

Goal is:

```
#mount 'line 1 from file 1' 'line 1 from file 2'
#mount 'line 2 from file 1' 'line 2 from file 2'
#mount 'line 3 from file 1' 'line 3 from file 2'
#mount 'line 4 from file 1' 'line 4 from file 2'
```

and so on till 100th line.

How can I do this in a script?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with paste.

```
while read a b ; do mount "$a" "$b" ; done < <(paste file1 file2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
paste file1 file2 | head -n100 | while read arg1 arg2; do mount "$arg1" "$arg2"; done
```